# Solving a system of algebraic and transcendental functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am attempting to solve a puzzle ([LINK](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/current-puzzle/)). As I have only taken up to multivariable calc, my college course knowledge hasn't helped. How do you solve a system of algebraic and transcendental functions? Do the regular methods of substitutions and elimination work with kinds of functions? I'm not looking for the answer, but would like some pointers in methodologies. The functions are below:

$$
2936 = \sqrt{U + E + E}
$$
$$
481729 = N + U
$$
$$
22130 = E - O + S
$$
$$
1281959 = S - C \cdot E \cdot U + N^{C}
$$
$$
85450 = C \cdot O
$$
$$
363508 = Olog_{E}N
$$
$$
200350 = \frac{C^{E}}{(S+U)^{C}}
$$
$$
84514 = (\frac{U}{C} - O)!
$$
$$
? = \frac{S}{C} + \frac{N + O + U}{E}
$$

Comment: If it's a puzzle, regular methods won't work unless it's a very boring puzzle. There's probably a trick.

Comment: Puzzles are not for everyone. I could never do math puzzles as a kid. When I was in grad school for a PhD in math I could overpower the high school puzzles with my knowledge and experience, but I never would've solved them in high school.

Comment: Matt, I do agree that I feel like I'm missing certain pieces of knowledge to solve this. Tried it through regular methods, but I wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: The last equation gives you the most information. It'll give you that $U/C-O$ is some reasonably small number. From there it'll probably be easier.

Comment: Except that's not the factorial of an integer. I didn't follow the link, did you copy this right?

Comment: Oops sorry. Forgot the last one, which is edited. The ? is supposed to be a a positive integer. So I'm guessing you can the factorial can be represented in some form of an irrational number?

Comment: There's no such thing as the factorial of anything that isn't a nonnegative integer. The gamma function is one possible extension, but I would never use the same symbol.

Comment: I'm having a fun time trying to solve this myself, thanks for posting. One thing I will point out is that nowhere did the puzzle say that any of those expressions are necessarily equal to the corresponding numbers. One other thing I observed is that the title of the puzzle is "*Long. Journey*" and that the letters used form the word UNESCO, suggesting a possible link? All of this is speculation of course... fun!

Comment: Just to elaborate on the "not necessarily equal" remark, this is probably the case since, as @MattSamuel pointed out, 84514 is not the factorial of any integer (and this is certainly a more preferable explanation to having to potentially use the inverse gamma function to solve a puzzle). Hope this helps somewhat, I'm getting nowhere!

Answer (score 1):

You should not solve the equations using regular methods.

Try to think about these few points:

1. The first letters in each of the first 6 equations form the word "UNESCO". Coincidence?
2. The title has the word Journey, what does that tell you?
3. Instead of writing it as 2E, the question says E+E on the first equation. Try to figure out what do the mathematical operations mean here.
4. 6 unknowns, 8 equations, we are given too many equations
5. The word "Long" in the title is written as "Long." and they are using long arrows instead of equal sign. What does the character '.' means? Why long arrows? What does long here refer to?
6. Usually, you assign a value to a variable, but here the direction of the arrow is clearly from a variable to a value. What does this mean?

I hope that helps you.